# On click of a button show a div for 1 second and then hide it?

Tags: jquery

On click of a button I want to show a div for 1 Second and then hide it:

```
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="infor">This is a test div</div>


  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#infor").hide();
      $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
    });
function AlertSave() {
   $("#infor").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

This is **[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3280/)**

Could you please tell me how to do it ??

Comment: Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/0zdLbqa7/?

Comment: Or this : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/h4JXs/3282/

Comment: Ha ha! I answered first @adeneo!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply chain `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` with a `delay()` call in between:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#infor").hide();
    $("#btnSave").click(AlertSave);
});
function AlertSave() {
    $("#infor").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cjwj6gvx/

Comment: @PreethiJain I answered first. Kindly have a look at my answer.

Comment: I forgot about the delay :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Your answer *as it was before I posted* did not have any of the shortcut methods I showed. Please do not try take credit away from others. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well, yeah, but leave the shortcut aside. `:)` The first answer I posted works too. Whatever, if that's guilty, I admit. Enjoy your vote up! Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#infor").hide();
      $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
    });
function AlertSave() {
   $("#infor").show();
   $("#infor").delay(1000).fadeOut();
}
```

I think the above piece of code will do the job , try it and let me know the outputs whether they are correct or not

Answer (score 0):

I came late but, just to mention that as well as *All Other* answers shown there're 2 other methods..

**1st Method:** by making use of CSS3 animation, and using jQuery to add the class that contains animation, then remove it after the animation duration ends like in this [**JS Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bo25bsdc/)

```js
var element =$('#infor');

$("#btnSave").click(AlertSave);

function AlertSave() {
 element.addClass('show-me');
  setTimeout(function () {
     element.removeClass('show-me');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#infor {
  opacity: 0;
}
.show-me {
  animation: foo 2s ease-in-out
}
@keyframes foo {
  0%, 99%, { opacity: 0; }
  25%, 75% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="infor">This is a test div</div>
```

---

**2nd Method:** making use of jQuery `.animate()` function like this [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6pLrvmzk/)

```js
var element = $('#infor');
element.animate({'opacity': 0}, 0);

$("#btnSave").click(AlertSave);

function AlertSave() {
  element.animate({'opacity':1}, 300).delay(1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
     element.animate({'opacity':0}, 300);
    }, 1600);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="infor">This is a test div</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this way:

```
function AlertSave() {
  $("#infor").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#infor").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0zdLbqa7/**

You can also use the shorthand:

```
$("#infor").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Snippets for Both:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#infor").hide();
  $("#btnSave").click(AlertSave);
});
function AlertSave() {
  $("#infor").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#infor").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="infor">This is a test div</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#infor").hide();
  $("#btnSave").click(AlertSave);
});
function AlertSave() {
  $("#infor").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="infor">This is a test div</div>
```

> **Note:** I would also advice you to change the `.click()` handler.